# Setting virtual hosts in xampp linux for port other than 80(Debian 6.0.4)

Tags: apache

How to set up virtual hosts for xampp linux in case of ports other than 80. Suppose I want to configure virtual hosts for port 5000. How can I do it? I am using Debian Squeeze 6.04.

```
NameVirtualHost *:5000
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla
    ServerName sitename
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
gedit /etc/hosts
```

where I have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sitename
```

I have uncommented virtual hosts entry in httpd.conf

But it is not working. Is this the right way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If the apache config of Xampp, you have to find the "Listen" directive, and add the appropriate port to it. You'll also have to copy the NameVirtualHost directive for your new port.

I don't know in which config file it's stored on Xampp, sorry. Probably in httpd.conf...

Comment: I have edited httpd.conf to make the necessary changes ie Listen :8008 but it is not working.How can i make it to work?

Comment: You also have to restart Apache (or maybe Xampp if you can't restart Apache individually) & add a NameVirtualHost *:8009